# Force Pex to ignore generated code, can I do it without a reference to the Pex assembly?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, pex

I'm trying to start using Pex, and I have certain code that I want it to ignore testing.

I create configuration sections for config files using the Configuration Section Designer addin.  Unfortunately the code generated is not quite perfect, because it doesn't do tests for nulls and other nice checks.  However, for now at least I want the code to be ignored when running pex explorations as I can't change the code without it being overwritten in future, and it's a known fault that we can work around.

I found the `PexInstrumentMarkedBy`and the `PexCoverageFilterMarkedBy` attributes, which seem like they may do the job (of ignoring code with the GeneratedCodeAttribute), but as far as I cam see I would need to put those in my assembly, and thus have a reference to the Pex framework in my operational assembly... not going to happen.

Does anyone have better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be an option, but here is a suggestion -  If I understand your question correctly, the only code you trying to avoid is the designer generated code. Since there is no way you can reference Pex assembly in your operational assembly, would you consider an alternative approach to creating Config Sections, i.e implement them as you would normally do.

Comment: Do you mean creating them without the designer addin?  I could but that would be terribly annoying, because then pex is getting in the way of me doing my work quickly, and that's not a great selling point for such a tool.